# How to store huge number of rows of data while processing.In REST is it valid?

Tags: c#, rest, optimization

Looking for a piece of advice......

I am analyzing an old C# web method to rewrite in REST. In the old method I observed that one private method is getting called multiple(nearly 25+) times. This private method connects to database and just calls simple select statement with simple where condition. This returns single row.

In my new method, I am planning to select the entire table content (400 rows approximately) and store in .net side whenever any data needed from this result set thought of querying it by writing LINQ or lambda. Is this the correct way of storing this huge dataset during this main method execution? Is this the correct approach?? How can I optimize? Can I store this data in a static datatable?

Comment: There are two methods of connecting to a database 1) Using a connection string and a client like oledb or sqlclient 2) Using Entiry Entity if quicker and you can use Linq statements.  Client you would use a DataAdapter and put into a datatable.Not sure why the old code was using a bunch of Where Statements.Suspect because the code didn't want to get ALL the data.Speed of a query is based on size of database and the amount of data returned.  It is faster to do filtering on server (using a stored procedure) than to return ALL data (more data transfered which is slower) and then filter in client.

Comment: In my old method everytime going to database and fetching a single row, this happening almost 25+ times of course many operations happening in between. So you are suggesting to call DBwith simple sp and not to get the entire table content(400 rows) onclient side. So my old method is in correct way?

Comment: You old method is probably correct.  It may be quicker to create a stored procedure in database and add the WHERE statements in the stored procedure instead of in c#.

Comment: Do you need to display the entire 400 rows into the client side?
I think the modern approach would be lazy loading. Which means you should fetch only a set of rows (10 or 25 rows), and when user wishes to view more, your web service will trigger to fetch the next 10 or 25 rows. This will reduce the load of retrieving the data and improve the user experience (cause the page can now load faster).
As for the choice of data storage at .net side, it highly depends on how you plan to use the data. I would usually store it as a List<ClassObject>.

Comment: I would agree with @jdweng in the respect that you leave data retrieval and filtering to the DB. That's the role of the DB and it does that job the best. If you have business logic to apply to the data that you have retrieved, then you would do it in .NET.

Comment: I need not to show all rows at once. my main method calls this private method almost 30 times, is 30 times db call is correct? instead of bringing all rows to client side and filter in .NET side? Is DB call not expensive? pls help on this

Comment: @San Can you share with us, why your method is calling this method 30x?
If it's retrieving the same set of data 30x, then perhaps you can implement cache.
If it's because user is modifying certain filter parameter, then invoking the Stored Procedure 30x is legitimate. 
SQL DB has its own memory, where tables that are frequently accessed, will be loaded into the memory cache and performance impact from the subsequent hits will be rather negligible.
Bringing out all rows is generally a bad practice, especially when you do not need all rows. Filter process is a lot slower at .NET too

Comment: There is not BEST method.  Whenever you write software there are always trade-offs.  when fetching data from a database you are looking at the maintainability of the software verses the speed and memory.  A SQL procedure language is not as robust as c#, but a Server usually is a faster machine with more memory.  And you have to look at the possibility of modifying the query and is the modification easier to make in c# or in a sql procedure.

Comment: my table is not a transactional table it's like master table may not grow to 500 rows in it's life time.table contains id and description etc., While main method logic runs it generates some ids, based on it I need to fetch description from the table. These ids not aware in advance. Based on parent method rows this SP calls happening 30 to 40 times also...So thought of getting all rows at once and modify the logic c# side accordingly. Confused in choosing the way.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends.

Calling Sql server select with where 25 times per one method is not good thing. 
Each out of process call consumes much more time comparing with the local one (despite that ADO Net connection caching whatever)

To cache 400 rows looks not a big deal actually if it is the same set for each 25 calls.
It is small enough to be processed by C# linq query in effective way.

However what about scalability? Sql server can handle hundred thousands of rows in effective way using indexes, special caching etc.

Let's imagine that database grows and you have 4M rows to be checked to get the one row. 
I do not think that it is fine to have 4M records to be read by C# and filtered locally in the memory.

So you have to check the data and the code that is written.

The best way is to mix two approaches into the one.

For example you can check why so many db calls are in one method. 
Is it possible to reduce db calls quantity?
Is there any way to do some join or additional calculations on the SQL server side? 
Actually SQL is much more than flat table storage tool.

You can create stored procedure (or two or three) and implement some logic using the SP to reduce db calls. To reduce db calls quantity and keep data on the SQL side at the same time.

Comment: Thanks oleksa and everyone for detailed explanation. Let me add some more points, the table which stores id, description which has 400 rows not a transactional table so may not increase more than 500 rows in it's life time. While executing the main method different IDs gets generated based on logic, to find out description with this id we call one simple GET Seored procedure by passing this ID, it returns description and some other 3 columns. But this process executes 30 times based on generated ids. We don't know before hand these unique ids. So can I replace with these many db calls with .

Comment: single db call which brings total record set to c# side.

Comment: @San aha, so you have SP with certain logic inside already. Are you going to replace the SP logic with the same on c#? It is possible but you should test performance before going to the production. Try to rewrite SP logic using the C# and test the performance.

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, the approach that I would recommend would be:

## Construct a stored procedure

Now, you may ask, why another stored procedure when you're already invoking a SELECT statement to the Database.

1. Separation of database logic from business logic. Ideally, your .NET code should only consists of business logic.
2. Unless you are already using Parameterized Query in your SELECT statement, otherwise, Stored Procedure offers:

   - Better protection against SQL Injection Attacks
   - Lower network traffic (sending Stored Procedure Name vs Dynamic Query)
   - SQL able to optimize Stored Procedure in its cached query plan better than Dynamic Query. Optimizing Query Plan
3. Retrieval of records via Stored Procedure will perform way better than using foreach/LINQ/Lambda in C#. Database is optimized for searching for data and it has larger memory and better CPU threading to handle these data retrieval operation. This is especially so if you have proper DB index on your search criteria. We will cover this in the next section.

Reference: [Dynamic SQL vs Stored Procedure](https://codingsight.com/dynamic-sql-vs-stored-procedure/)

## Create a non-clustered index for your search criteria

If your search criteria is not currently indexed, you may consider creating a non-clustered index for that column. This will further improve your retrieval speed.

With these in place, you can support up to thousands of retrieval to this table without any significant impact to your application performance.